# I am trying to set a background image in Android using jetpack compose but the image cant fill the whole page

Tags: kotlin, background, android-jetpack-compose, appbar, scaffold

1. i want to fill the image to max size of page and fill the edges below the appbar.
2. i can fill the image to full background without using scaffold but in this case i need to use scaffold.
3. the screenshot is attached with the question for better understanding
4. u can check it by tapping on the link
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvlO5.png)

```
@Composable
fun ScaffoldBackground() {

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxHeight(0.2f)
                    .clip(
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(bottomEnd = 30.dp, bottomStart = 30.dp)
                    ),

                // Provide Title
                title = {
                    Text(
                        text = "Dashboard",
                    )

                }
            )
        },
    ) {

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize(), 
                painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background),
                contentDescription = "background_image",
                contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
            )


        }

    }
}
```

[the image cant fill the the edges of app bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Zs4t.png)

Comment: You want your image to go behind the topAppBar (a part of image will get cut) ?

Comment: yes!!!! but because of scaffold we cant do that

Comment: Don't use scaffold for the top level then. Use a Box. Inside that put your Scaffold and image with `fillMaxSize`.

Comment: it will give the same response... adding a box will not change anything

Comment: can you please share your code

Comment: trying to save value of my edit text field after changing to one activity to 2nd activity and then return to 1st activity in jetpack compose, can u help with this arpit

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I tried this code and it's working. The important thing here is to make sure that the content you put inside `Scaffold` should have some transparent area otherwise the background image won't be visible.

```kotlin
Box {
    Image(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background),
        contentDescription = "background_image",
        contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
    )
    Scaffold(
        backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,   // Make the background transparent
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxHeight(0.2f)
                    .clip(
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                            bottomEnd = 30.dp,
                            bottomStart = 30.dp
                        )
                    ),
                title = {
                    Text(text = "Dashboard")
                }
            )
        },
    ) {
        // Scaffold content
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help... everytime i forgot to add  backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,  to scaffold